# A unit cell for graphene

Tags: crystal-structure, molecular-structure

In a study I have run into some questions asking for "*How many atoms are contained in the unit cell*" for **graphene**. I have some trouble understanding the unit cell of graphene which is always depicted as a mono-layer of atoms. What is a unit cell in a mono-layer?

The closest I could find is something like [this picture](http://graphene.nus.edu.sg/content/graphene):

[image]

The upper right image shows something soon-to-be a hexagonal structure. But when is such structure actually appearing?

Comment: well considering graphene is a single layer of carbon atoms it's not really appropriate to try and define a unit cell.

Comment: I would go for one atom in special position (origin) and a planar hexagonal group p6mm, but as my *International Tables for Crystallography* are at university I can be mistaken.

Comment: The upper-right picture is graph*ite*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphite

Comment: As graphene isn't crystalline, what sense would it have to apply rules of crystalline structure to it?

Comment: Related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/12023/5

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The unit cell for graphene is a two-dimensional rhombus according to the figure shown on page 31 of [this paper.](https://www.ae.utexas.edu/~ruihuang/papers/JMPS03.pdf)$^1$ (also [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222517036_Internal_lattice_relaxation_of_single-layer_graphene_under_in-plane_deformation).) The result is that two atoms are contained per unit cell. The upper right structure actually appearing in graphite, stacked layers of graphene.

[image]

$^1$Zhou, J; Huang, R. Internal lattice relaxation of single-layer graphene under in-plane deformation. Journal of the Mechanics and Physics of Solids, 2008, 56(4), 1609-1623. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmps.2007.07.013

Answer (score 3):

Bit late,  but a unit cell of graphene is just the 'surface' area of 2 carbon atoms.

[image]

This area is 0,052 nm2, which gives us a density of 0,77 mg/m2.

Same principle for all monolayer materials.